# Placing JButton inside JPanel inside JFrame with variable outcomes

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm having an extremely confounding problem with a simple(?) concept. I am trying to learn the basics of `JFrame`, `JPanel`, etc, and am right now trying to implement a simple task. I want to have a big `JFrame` called canvas and inside 2 `JPanel`'s right next to each other with no margin or anything. Inside those two JPanels, I have a button covering a colored rectangle. When you click on the button the button is supposed to disappear and show the color. My problems are many.

The code seems to have a life of its own. Even using a get message inside a print statement will cause the output to change. As for the output itself, at first glance, it looks fine, two buttons side by side named correctly.

However, when you click on button 1, both buttons disappear, and a third button, named button two appears in the top right. When you click the new button, it disables but does not disappear.

Sometimes when you click button 1, the third button 2 also appears, but the original button 2 only disables not hides. Furthermore, the entire background is blue, rather than red and blue like it should be. An entirely new set of events happens when you click button2 but hopefully this may be enough to help you.

Thanks so much!

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class testbig {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame canvas = new JFrame("canvas");
        canvas.setSize(400,400);
        canvas.setVisible(true);
        canvas.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        canvas.setLayout(null);

        testinner temp = new testinner("1",Color.blue);
        temp.setBounds(0,0,200,400);
        canvas.getContentPane().add(temp);

        testinner temp2=new testinner("2",Color.red);
        temp2.setBounds(200,0,200,400);
        canvas.getContentPane().add(temp2);
    }
}
public class testinner extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    private JButton button;

    private Color color2;
    public testinner(String title,Color color) {
        super();
        color2=color;
        setSize(200,400);
        setBackground(color);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        button=new JButton(title);
        button.setBounds(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
        button.setVisible(true);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        //panel.add(label);
        add(button);
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics gr) {
        gr.setColor(color2);
        gr.fillRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());

    }
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent evt){
        button.setEnabled(false);
        button.setVisible(false);
        //System.out.println(this);
        //shown.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be adding 'getX' to your `fillRect`, or the `setBounds` of your button. They should be values relative to the container they are in. That goes for your `paintComponent` too.

Answer (score 2):

Lets look at what you've done. You've created a JFrame with a null layout. So that means it doesn't manage the size or position of it's children. ( Some might say it is a negligent parent. )

That means both of your JPanels *should* remember the `setBounds` call you made to them. Which sets *both* their size and position. So your `setSize` call is redundant.

You've set your JPanels to have a `flowLayout` layout manager. That means they do try to manage the size and position of their children. It's not always immediate.

You call setBounds on your buttons. Now they're really messed up. First, they have their own bounds, and sizes. *Don't call setBound on non-custom components*. Actually, it's better not to use it at all.

The first panel is ok. You set the bounds of your button to be (0, 0, 200, 400). That is within the JPanel that it is intended to draw on.

The second panel is not ok. The bounds of your button is (200, 0, 200, 400) your component is is 200 wide, so you've give the button the space outside of the panel to draw on. Then your paint component is also filling a rectangle *outside of your jpanel*.

So you're buttons have a size and position, that will be changed the first chance you ask your layout manager to do something.

The following code manages what I assume you are trying to do. There are two colored panels, each showing a JButton. When you click it it goes away. It's mostly what you have with some of the redundant bits removed.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class TestBig {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame canvas = new JFrame("canvas");
        canvas.setSize(400,400);

        canvas.setLayout(null);

        JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel( new FlowLayout(0, 0, 0) );
        leftPanel.setOpaque(true);
        leftPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
        rightPanel.setOpaque(true);
        rightPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);

        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(200, 400, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 400);
        g.dispose();

        JButton left = new JButton(new ImageIcon(img));
        left.setBorder(null);
        left.addActionListener( evt->{
            left.setVisible(false);
        });

        JButton right = new JButton("right");
        right.addActionListener( evt -> {
            right.setVisible(false);
        });

        leftPanel.add(left);
        rightPanel.add(right);

        canvas.add(leftPanel);
        canvas.add(rightPanel);

        leftPanel.setBounds( 0, 0, 200, 400);
        rightPanel.setBounds(200, 0, 200, 400);

        canvas.setVisible(true);
        canvas.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's helpful. Your code works, and I wanted to make it so the button fills the entire JPanel. Therefore, I added this line: left.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(leftPanel.getBounds().width,leftPanel.getBounds().height)) for left and right immediately after their ActionListeners. Unfortunately they don't quite take up the entire space. Is this because there is a default FlowLayout for the Panel? Should I make it null and set bounds for the buttons even though you said not to?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Arneya possibly. setBounds is something your layout manager handles. So when you set it on an object in a layout, the layout manager might change it. One answer is what you suggest, use a null layout and setBounds. I think you can see the issues with this, it doesn't adapt well to different size displays, or different fonts. Extending it is much harder. Beyond that, if it is doing what you want it is fine.

Comment: And yes, the FlowLayout has a border, you can check the default options on it, https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/FlowLayout.html#%3Cinit%3E(int,int,int) but I think you'll find even when the JButton extends the full size of the panel there will be a border. You might want to consider making an Image/Icon and using that on your Panel.

Comment: @Arneya I have updated the answer to fill the left button with a solid color/image. I also made the FlowLayout have 0px padding. I think the left panel looks how you want it.